# Accesing a MainActivity object from another class

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a difficult situation with an android program im writing. So.. :
I have created a GoogleMap object (theMap) in MainActivity.Then I start a new Activity called GetDirections and it starts a new Class called RequestDirection(Non-Activity).The class RequestDirection performs Google Directions API request and parses the JSON result to create a PolylineOptions object. So HOW can i access the GoogleMap object (theMap) to add the polyline???
Example code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public GoogleMap theMap;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
locationIcon=R.drawable.red_pin;

    theMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }}

public class GetDirections extends Activity{
//ask user to set Start/Destination Point

RequestDirection req= new RequestDirection();
req.execute();
finish();
}

public class RequestDirection extends AsyncTask {

doInBackground( ){
//returns the json string
}

onPostExecute( ){
PolylineOptions options= (the overview polyline points)
}

}
```

Note that all 3 classes are NOT nested.they are separate files

I could use mainActivity context and pass it to a new class but now i start a new Activity and i istantiate the class from there.

What can i do?? I wasted a whole day and no solution..

---

Added the exceptions for   dst  suggestion:

```
08-19 03:13:38.127: W/dalvikvm(1871): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.ceid.CeidMaps/com.ceid.CeidMaps.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.ceid.CeidMaps.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:162)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
08-19 03:13:38.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Which line is `MainActivity.java:162`?

Comment: PolylineOptions opt= data.getParcelableExtra("options");
this is inside the OnActivityresult override

Comment: In that case, `data` is null. Verify the result code is the same as you set in [`setResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29), and that the `Intent data` parameter you set there is non-null.

Comment: i didnt used at all the setResult() method... i just used the method putExtra("options",(here i inserted the polyline object)  )

Comment: where can i use setResult?

Comment: you must use `setResult` to recive an `Intent` in your `onActivityResult` method. Use that method at the place of your current `putExtra`: create a `final Intent intent = new Intent()`, put your extra into it and call `setResult(RESULT_FIRST_USER, intent)`

Comment: Ohhhh i just saw that... now it works ok!! i totally forgot to use setResult, sry..This way it works Thx man!! Can i ask one last?
If i want to interact after with this polyline and make it onClick to show details of current point do u suggest a better way to communicate through those classes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35716/discussion-between-dst-and-greekburner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably return the polyline [as a result](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) of your `GetDirections` activity. You can then add the polyline from within the `MainActivity`. That way your UI is only updated from the enclosing `Activity`, and not from another `Activity` (which would be against Androids code style, although it might be possible).

Comment: I tried it also but i had some nullexception errors..i think the problem for this is the asynctask that runs in background..

Comment: @GreekBurner please add the exceptions to your question (logcat)

Comment: well: i tried passing the GetDirections context as a parameter in req creation.And in onPostExecute i called ((GetDirections)context).getIntent().putExtra("options",optionspolyline); and finish()
on main Activity i implemented the OnActivityResult with getParcelableExtra("options");

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your MainActivity is always going to come first, a simple way to allow access to the `GoogleMap` object is to make is `static`. For instance instead of `public GoogleMap theMap` put `public static GoogleMap theMap`. Then from any other class you can call `MainActivity.theMap` to access that object.

If the situation gets more complicated there are other better ways to do it, but if it's as simple as just getting the object, this way will definitely work.

Comment: I know this the first thing i tried.. But this doesnt help me coz MainActivity doesnt come first always, so i have to try another solution. Thx anyway!! :)

Comment: Please do not use this method in any case, as even if the `MainActivity` comes first when calling the application the regular way there is a chance that it will get destroyed by the OS (or other bad things happen). That's not the way Android is intended to be used.